# EF Core Table does not exist when joining from multiple DbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.0

I am facing an issue when trying to join 2 tables from 2 DbContext which represents different databases.

I am using Fluent API to create foreign key relationship between 2 tables.
Here are the Dbcontext configuration and models.

```
public class DbContextDemo1: DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Agency> Agencies { get; set; }

   public DbContextDemo1(DbContextOptions<DbContextDemo1> options)
        : base(options)
   {
   }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("db1")
                    .Entity<Agency>()
                    .ToTable("agencies")
                    .HasKey(agency => agency.Id)
                    .HasOne(agency => agency.AgencyApp)
                    .WithOne(app => app.Agency)
                    .HasForeignKey<Agency>(agency => agency.Id);

    }
}

public class DbContextDemo2: DbContext
{
   public DbSet<AgencyApp> AgencyApps { get; set; }

   public DbContextDemo2(DbContextOptions<DbContextDemo2> options)
        : base(options)
   {
   }
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("db2")
                    .Entity<AgencyApp>()
                    .ToTable("agenciesapps")
                    .HasKey(app => app .Id)
                    .HasOne(app=> app.Agency)
                    .WithOne(agency => agency.AgencyApp)
                    .HasForeignKey<AgencyApp>(app=> app.AgencyId);         

    }
}
```

Here are the Models:

```
public class Agency
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public AgencyApp AgencyApp { get; set; }
}

public class AgencyApp
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid AgencyId { get; set; }

    public Agency Agency { get; set; }
}
```

Now, When I try to get Agencies data along with AgencyApp.

```
var result = _dbContextDemo1.Agencies.Include(agency => agency.AgencyApplication)
```

It throws an error

> "Table 'db2.agenciesapps' doesn't exist".

I can see in server console it is doing inner join between these two tables.

Help would be hightly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot join across databases. You'll have to use two separate queries:

```
var agencies = await _dbContextDemo1.Agencies.ToListAsync();
var agencyApps = await _dbContextDemo2.AgencyApps.Where(x => agencies.Select(a => a.Id).Contains(x.AgencyId)).ToListAsync();
```

Note: Since you're selecting all agencies, you can technically just select all agency applications as well, but filtering by the ids of the agencies that were selected works better if you end up filtering that set as well.

Then you can map the data from the second query over:

```
agencies.ForEach(x => x.AgencyApp = agencyApps.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AgencyId == x.Id));
```

Comment: My apologies for not seeing message on time, but I come up with the same idea like yours later which I have mentioned in the above comment for Marcus Höglund.
Appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Including, or joining, tables from different contexts are not supported because
the contexts can be connected to different db servers.

Instead of using different context, add the entities to the same context (*Why would you even want to have two different context for them?*)

```
public class DbContextDemo1: DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Agency> Agencies { get; set; }
   public DbSet<AgencyApp> AgencyApps { get; set; }

   public DbContextDemo1(DbContextOptions<DbContextDemo1> options)
        : base(options)
   {
   }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("db1")
                    .Entity<Agency>()
                    .ToTable("agencies")
                    .HasKey(agency => agency.Id)
                    .HasOne(agency => agency.AgencyApp)
                    .WithOne(app => app.Agency)
                    .HasForeignKey<Agency>(agency => agency.Id);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("db1")
                    .Entity<AgencyApp>()
                    .ToTable("agenciesapps")
                    .HasKey(app => app .Id)
                    .HasOne(app=> app.Agency)
                    .WithOne(agency => agency.AgencyApp)
                    .HasForeignKey<AgencyApp>(app=> app.AgencyId); 

    }
}
```

If you really need to have them on two different contexts then you need to fetch all entities to memory and then join them together (*this is not a good idea as you need to fetch all agencies to memory*)

```
var agencies = _dbContextDemo1.Agencies.ToList();
foreach(var agency in agencies)
{
    agency.AgencyApps = _dbContextDemo2.AgencyApps.FirstOrDefault(a=> a.AgencyId == agency.Id);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. The reason behind I want to have in different context is because AgencyApp is in db2 and Agency is in db1. I tried your first approach, adding AgencyApp in same DbContext, but what is happening is, It is treating Agency table as a table of db2, which should be db1.
So throwing error, db2.agencies' doesn't exist.

Comment: @Saya ok, i also added a working solution for different contexts at the bottom of my answer

Comment: Second solution won't work out, because agencies have more than 500 rows of data, and for each you are hitting into the database inside loop. Thats not good.
I worked it out by creating a separate DbContext for AgencyApp table and get all those data from it and Join it in C# sharp side. Like this: `_dbContextDemo1.Agencies.Where(a => agencyIds.Contains(a.Id)); ` 
where agencyIds are Ids I took from _dbContextDemo2.
Again, appreciate your trying.